# Serialising .NET object to JSON: `double` property value gets written as a different value with extra decimal places

Tags: .net, serialization, double, precision, system.text.json

I'm using `System.Text.Json` to (de)serialise between .NET Well class object and JSON. The Well class object has a List of layers `List<Layer> layers`, and the Layer class has a list of Items `List<Item> items` The `Item` class has properties such as `string name`, `double length`. The classes are as below:

```
public class Well
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public List<Layer> layers {get; set;}
    
    public void serialiseJSON()
    {
        string fileName = "well.json";
        string jsonString = JsonSerialiser.Serialize(this);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonString);
        return;
    }
}
```

```
public class Layer
{
    public string name {get; set;};
    public List<Item> items {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Item
{
    public string name {get; set;};
    public double length {get; set;}
}
```

for example when the `item.length` value is `70.8`, it gets written to file as `70.799999999999997` after serialising the Well. As far as I can understand, and please correct me if I'm wrong, this is due to the the precision of the double data type but I don't udnerstand why the double value gets written differently. The class instance has the correct value but serialising it to a json file changes it in the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: I do not wish to save the double values as string in my json file for consistency reasons.**

Comment: What version of System.Text.Json you are using?

Comment: You're hitting the issue from [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004).  `double` is a **base 2 fraction** not a base 10 fraction, and `0.8` = `4/5` is a **continuing fraction** in base 2: `0.110011001100...`  where `.1100` is a repeating decimal.  Thus you never had a double value of `70.8`, you had something very close, which is what got serialized.  If you need true decimal precision, use `decimal` rather than `double`.  See also [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/618535) and https://floating-point-gui.de/.

Comment: @Mathan it's version 7.0.3

Comment: @dbc Alright that's helpful. I've got them now as `decimal`. However, I have to use those `decimal` types for calculations and for plots using LightningChart and they're expected to be in the `double` type. The workaround is that I cast as `(double) start` for the calculations but keep them as `decimal` in the class definitions. Would this be a clean solution?

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad I am sorry but you need to post your example that causes the problem. I was trying to serialize your classes with length=7.8 and I could not  find any problem.

Comment: @Serge that is the example. I deserialise a JSON file into a Well using `Well well = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Well>(jsonWell);`. This works and loads the JSON into the well.  The JSON file has numeric values that are of `double` in the `Well` class. Then I simply serialise the object using `well.SerialiseToJSON()`, which caused the problem.

However, using `decimal` class members seems to work and I just cast the values as `(double)` when I use it for calculations etc. Serialising the decimal values does not seem to cause the precision difference in file

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad  I used just JsonSerializer.Serialize and didn't have any problem.

Comment: @Serge that is strange. Could it be because of a different version of `System.Text.Json` as @Mathan questioned?

Either way, having it as `decimal` type seems to work fine for (de)serialisation and just casting the value as `double` for performing calculations. The follow up question with that is will I lose precision when I do casting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by changing the `Item` members to `decimal` type

```
public class Item
{
    public string name {get; set;};
    public decimal length {get; set;}
}
```